# Rock Paper Scissors game returns same result

Tags: javascript, html, function, loops

So I'm having some difficulty with my code (hence the post). I'm trying to make it so where when you click on the picture of the rock, the game begins and it returns the computer's decision. It worked before when I prompted the user but since I've rewritten the logic when I click on the rock, it only returns one answer. Is it because of the lack of loops? I assumed each time I would click on the icon, a different answer would display. I haven't done the code for the other options yet because I figured I would use similar logic for the other options. The only thing I can think of is that because I'm not using a loop, the game basically plays only 1 round.

```
const rock = document.querySelector('.rock');
const paper = document.querySelector('.paper');
const scissors = document.querySelector('.scissors');
const h3 = document.querySelector('h3');

let computerScore = 0;
let playerScore = 0;

function computerPlay() {
    var choice = Math.floor(Math.random() * 3 ) + 1; //generate a number 1-3 to find computer choice
    if(choice == 1) {
        return 'rock';
    }
    else if(choice == 2) {
        return 'paper';
    }
    else {
        return 'scissors'

    }
} 





//     function playGame(computerChoice) {
//     // let round = 0
//     // while(round < 6) {
//     var playerChoice = playerRock || playerPaper || playerScissors;
//     var computerChoice = computerPlay();
//     if(playerChoice === computerChoice) {
//       console.log('Tie!');
//       round++;
//     }
    
//     else if(playerChoice == 'rock' && computerChoice == 'scissors') {
//         playerScore++;
//         console.log(`Player chose rock and computer chose scissors! The player wins! Player: ${playerScore} Computer:${computerScore}`);
//         round++;
//     }
//     else if(playerChoice == 'paper' && computerChoice == 'rock') {
//         playerScore++;
//         round++;
//         console.log(`Player chose paper and computer chose rock! The player wins! Player: ${playerScore} Computer:${computerScore}`);
//     }
//     else if(playerChoice == 'scissors' && computerChoice == 'paper') {
//         playerScore++;
//         round++;
//         console.log(`Player chose scissors and computer chose paper! The player wins! Player: ${playerScore} Computer:${computerScore}`);
//     }
//     else {
//         computerScore++;
//         console.log(`The player chose ${playerChoice} and the computer chose ${computerChoice}! The computer wins! Player: ${playerScore} Computer: ${computerScore}.`)
//     }
// //   } 
//   }


// computerPlay()
// playerChoice()
// console.log(playGame())

function playGame(computerChoice) {
    computerChoice = computerPlay();
    let result;

    rock.addEventListener('click', () => {
        if(computerChoice == 'rock') {
            result = `The computer chose ${computerChoice} and you chose rock! It's a tie!`;
            h3.textContent = result;
            
        }
        else if(computerChoice == 'paper') {
            result = `The computer chose ${computerChoice} and you chose rock! You lose!`;
            h3.textContent = result;
            computerScore++;
     
        }
        else {
            result = `The computer chose ${computerChoice} and you chose rock! You win!`; 
            h3.textContent = result;
            playerScore++;

        }
    });
    let playerPaper = paper.addEventListener('click', () => {
        return 'paper'
    });
    let playerScissors = scissors.addEventListener('click', () => {
        return 'scissors'
    })

}
playGame()
console.log(playGame())
```

This is what I have so far. Initially, I didn't have a result variable but I thought that might help.

Comment: why do you take `computerChoice` as an argument and then immediately run the `computerPlay` function?

Comment: @Jhecht lol sorry, I'm kind of new to coding. Is there a better way to do that? I just figured i couldn't call the function as a parameter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When calling `playGame()` once, `computerChoice` is only generated once. Everytime you click on rock paper or scissor it evaluates the players choice, but the computers choice has never changed. If it chooses rock at the beginning it will always compare the users choice to rock.

Either take the eventListeners out of the playGame function and call playGame after the result is shown (Recursive-style loop)

Or, after the result is shown reset computerChoice to the result of another computerPlay() call. You can add `computerChoice = computerPlay()` to the end of your event listener function after the else statement to run regardless of the outcome.

Comment: This worked perfectly! Thanks so much for the help!

Answer (score 0):

You need to do some changes ...

1- add event at first time
add `useChoice`variable

and show reult of game on click

```js
const rock = document.querySelector('.rock');
const paper = document.querySelector('.paper');
const scissors = document.querySelector('.scissors');
const h3 = document.querySelector('h3');

let computerScore = 0;
let playerScore = 0;
let computerChoice = "";
let userChoice = "";

rock.addEventListener('click', () => {
    userChoice = "rock";
    ShowResult() 
});
  paper.addEventListener('click', () => {
    userChoice = 'paper';
    ShowResult() 
});
  scissors.addEventListener('click', () => {
    userChoice = 'scissors';
    ShowResult() 
})


function computerPlay() {
    var choice = Math.floor(Math.random() * 3) + 1; //generate a number 1-3 to find computer choice
    if (choice == 1) {
        return 'rock';
    }
    else if (choice == 2) {
        return 'paper';
    }
    else {
        return 'scissors'

    }
}





//     function playGame(computerChoice) {
//     // let round = 0
//     // while(round < 6) {
//     var playerChoice = playerRock || playerPaper || playerScissors;
//     var computerChoice = computerPlay();
//     if(playerChoice === computerChoice) {
//       console.log('Tie!');
//       round++;
//     }

//     else if(playerChoice == 'rock' && computerChoice == 'scissors') {
//         playerScore++;
//         console.log(`Player chose rock and computer chose scissors! The player wins! Player: ${playerScore} Computer:${computerScore}`);
//         round++;
//     }
//     else if(playerChoice == 'paper' && computerChoice == 'rock') {
//         playerScore++;
//         round++;
//         console.log(`Player chose paper and computer chose rock! The player wins! Player: ${playerScore} Computer:${computerScore}`);
//     }
//     else if(playerChoice == 'scissors' && computerChoice == 'paper') {
//         playerScore++;
//         round++;
//         console.log(`Player chose scissors and computer chose paper! The player wins! Player: ${playerScore} Computer:${computerScore}`);
//     }
//     else {
//         computerScore++;
//         console.log(`The player chose ${playerChoice} and the computer chose ${computerChoice}! The computer wins! Player: ${playerScore} Computer: ${computerScore}.`)
//     }
// //   } 
//   }


// computerPlay()
// playerChoice()
// console.log(playGame())

function ShowResult() {
    if (computerChoice == userChoice) {
        result = `The computer chose ${computerChoice} and you chose ${userChoice}! It's a tie!`;
        h3.textContent = result;

    } else if (
        computerChoice == 'paper' && userChoice == "rock"
        || computerChoice == 'scissors' && userChoice == "paper"
        || computerChoice == 'rock' && userChoice == "scissors"
    ) {
        result = `The computer chose ${computerChoice} and you chose ${userChoice}! You lose!`;
        h3.textContent = result;
        computerScore++;

    } else {
        result = `The computer chose ${computerChoice} and you chose ${userChoice}! You win!`;
         playerScore++;
    h3.textContent = result + playerScore ; 

    }


playGame()

}


function playGame() {
    computerChoice = computerPlay();
    console.log( "Computer Choice:" + computerChoice);


   

}
playGame()
```

```html
   <div class="rock">rock</div>
    <div class="paper">paper</div>
    <div class="scissors">scissors</div>
    <h3></h3>
```

Comment: Thanks so much for the tip! I didn't know that i could call a function as an argument and your snippet really helped show it. I appreciate it!